# Entity Frameworks and Child Table Composite Key

Tags: entity-framework, odata, entity-framework-core

I have multiple issues with EF 2.1 Core, both issues do not exist in my current production EF6 implementation... This post is about my first issue. The second problem i will detail is a bit more complex, but will save that for another post.

I have, for the purposes of this post, a parent\child relationship with two SQL Server tables;

```
Device Table
DeviceID  int (autoincrement key)
Name  varchar(50)
More fields...

Events Table
DeviceID { half composite key, one to many relationship with parent}
EventStamp DateTime { half of composite key }
EventText varchar(max)
More fields...
```

So, in my previous iteration (EF6) I ran scaffolding in VS 2015 (database first implementation) and it gave me all my classes, and database context. I placed them in my web api 2 application, defined the ODATA 4 IEDMModel, used the model builder and like magic I had an OData 4 web service that supplied all my information to my custom mobile app...

In the previous app, I was able to hit the service like "http://server/devices" and I would get a full list of ALL devices. adding (N) where N is a number, would find the specific single indexed entity. I could then append ...devices(4)/events... and I would get ALL the events for that device... and with some odata query syntax i could get specific detail from within the event entity... BEAUTIFUL! Simple ODATA 4 query syntax is the real power here! Including reversing the scenario... going reverse lookup from the events first was extremely helpful.

In order for Odata 4 to work, I have to define the EDM model. In EF6 everything works just fine. In EF Core 2.1. The "Events" table throws an error on running the web service... Table "Events" does not have a primary key. This in fact is NOT true, and this was not a problem in the previous EF6 version, using ODATA 4. I tried several different theories, including Fluent approach, but nothing changes the fact that in the "startup.cs" I get the error early, while the system is initializing...

Anybody have a thought here?

Comment: Please provide the relevant entity model (entity classes, context, fluent configuration) for the tables in question.

Comment: You're virtually repeating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51618529/861716) which wasn't quite clear either. What used to work isn't really relevant here and you may as well skip that part. Just list the steps you took to create OData controllers off of the EF-core model (that should also be included).